# How do I transpile TypeScript to ES6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Basically I need to be able to write TypeScript code in my IDE (this introduces great ease to development), compile it to ES6 and then apply `babel.js` (as all browsers doesn't support most ES6) to get the resulting ES5 scripts.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need ES6 as the output? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: TypeScript 1.5 has an ES6 output mode. You can then run that resulting Javascript through Babel.

Comment: why not compile to es5 at once?

Comment: I want to be able to write ES6 application using Typescript that can be deployed now, but with when ES6 will come to rule I will remove babel and get the same result.

Comment: Not sure what project this is, but II'll take some years before a significant percentage of the people on the internet are using an up-to-date browser.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to compile TypeScript to ES6, just to convert it to ES5, when TypeScript can be compiled straight into ES5. The same TypeScript codebase can be pretty much converted both to ES5 and 6, so that if you compile your code into ES5 now, you can later recompile your entire codebase into ES6 without changing a single line.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes.

You can target TypeScript compiler to ES6.

For example add this to your command line args:

```
--target es6
```

Answer (score 29):

Yes, You can.

Either by adding `--target es2015`, or by adding `target` to Your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

Supported options for target are:

- "ES3" (default)
- "ES5"
- "ES6"/"ES2015"
- "ES2016"
- "ES2017"
- "ESNext"

---

There are a lot of more config options. You can explore them here:
[Compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Some options are only allowed in `tsconfig.json`, and not through command-line switches.

Answer (score 5):

You can use typescript to write pure ES6 and then transpile to ES3 or ES5. Since typescript is ES6 plus goodies.

See it as using Less to write your css, you can write pure CSS in a less file and it will compile just fine.

For typescript 1.8 language spec:

> TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. TypeScript syntax is a superset of ECMAScript 2015 (ES2015) syntax. Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program.
>
> TypeScript syntax includes all features of ECMAScript 2015, including classes and modules, and provides the ability to translate these features into ECMAScript 3 or 5 compliant code.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is more or less ES6 with very little syntactic sugar.
I would suggest you write Vanilla ES6 instead of TypeScript but on the other hand TypeScript tooling is worth putting in the extra effort to write TypeScript and transpile it into ES6 and let Babel do the rest.

Here is a more convenient option like noted in a comment, from TypeScript 1.5 you have the ability to transpile to ES6.

Comment: are all features of ES6 present in that transpiler?

Comment: except typescript has optional typing, interfaces to allow strong typing of untyped js dependencies, and many more things. it's ES6 at the core, but much more.

Comment: isn't one of the major benefits to writing Typescript the fact that it has to be compiled? And that will help you find bugs?

Comment: I found that TypeScript does not think that `String.repeat()` exists.