# Does TypeScript have an equivalent of ES6 "Sets"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, set

I want to extract all the unique properties from an array of objects, you can do so in ES6 very cleanly using the spread operator and the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) so:

```
var arr = [ {foo:1, bar:2}, {foo:2, bar:3}, {foo:3, bar:3} ]   
const uniqueBars = [... new Set(arr.map(obj => obj.bar))];

>> [2, 3]
```

However, in TypeScript 1.8.31 this gives me the build error:

> Cannot find name 'Set'

I know I can force VS to ignore it by using

```
declare var Set;
```

But I'm hoping for something TypeScript will compile into non-ES6 so that it could be used on older systems.

Does anyone know if there's such a feature I could use?

**Edit**:

Actually, even when I use `declare var Set;`, the above code compiles but throws this error repeatedly, so I'm not sure how to use it even without compiling down:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).slice is not a function

How can I update my code to use `Set` in TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 typescript can't find names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332394/angular-2-typescript-cant-find-names)

Comment: TS doesn't have to have an equivalent of this, because TS transpiles to JS, and `Set` is polyfillable JS feature. This is a duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/a/41608156/3731501 in particular.

Comment: I suppose you could also [compile the typescript to ES6 code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439869/can-typescript-compile-to-es6-code) and then transpile that to ES5 with something like babel.  That would allow you to use all the ES6 collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you compile to ES5 or older Typescript only adds the syntactic changes from ES6. It doesn't add any of the standard library objects.

If you want those I suggest you look into something like [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.

One of the issues appears to be that typescript trys to use

```
ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).slice is not a function
```

instead of Array.from();

in any event this code worked for me in my Angular 4 applicaiton

```
Array.from(new Set(Array)).sort(this.compareNumbers)
```

hope this helps someone

Comment: I'm getting error `Argument of type 'ArrayConstructor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<{}>'.
  Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'ArrayConstructor'.`

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?   This still works for me in production

Comment: so, what I did was the same, `let set = new Set();` while `import 'core-js/es6/set';` imported in my polyfills.ts

Comment: Thank you! Confirming `[...Array.from(new Set([...arr1, ...arr2]))]` works, but `[...(new Set([...arr1, ...arr2]))]` gave the `(intermediate value).slice is not a function` error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [type script library](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections). Or maybe create your one set class using reference from this library