# Convert json response to table

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm trying to convert json response to array which accepts my table (component from devextreme). I'm trying to do that on angular 6. Json looks like that:

```
"data": [
            {
                "type": "A",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "153"
            },
            {
                "type": "B",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "888"
            },
            {
                "type": "C",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "999"
            },
            {
                "type": "D",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "555"
            },
            {
                "type": "A",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "148"
            },
            {
                "type": "B",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "222"
            },
            {
                "type": "C",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "555"
            },
            {
                "type": "D",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "666"
            },
            {
                "type": "A",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "156"
            },
            {
                "type": "B",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "111"
            },
            {
                "type": "C",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "333"
            },
            {
                "type": "D",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "999"
            }
],
        "number": "111-111"
   }
]
```

And I need to transform it to this format:

```
[{
    month: '2018-05',
    A: 153,
    B: 888,
    C: 999,
    D: 555
  },
  {
    month: '2018-06',
    A: 148,
    B: 222,
    C: 555,
    D: 666
  },
  {
    month: '2018-07',
    A: 156,
    B: 111,
    C: 333,
    D: 999
  }]
```

Number of types can change (so there could be A and B only for example). Can anybody help me with that ? I'm using this component to present data at website https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/SimpleArray/Angular/Light/

Comment: I didn't mention that the number of types can change (so there could be only A,B and C for example) sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would approach your problem:

1) Get the list of types and dates from your data source. We make use of JavaScript's [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store the values so that the values will be unique (without duplicates).

The value from `date` will be considered as the unique key for each object in the result array, and the `type` will be the other properties of the result ('A', 'B', 'C', and 'D')

2) Once we have those 2 arrays, we will iterate through the original list to generate the object. The values of properties `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` are populated by filtering the `date` and `type` from the original `list`.

```js
const list = {"data":[{"type":"A","date":"2018-05","value":"153"},{"type":"B","date":"2018-05","value":"888"},{"type":"C","date":"2018-05","value":"999"},{"type":"D","date":"2018-05","value":"555"},{"type":"A","date":"2018-06","value":"148"},{"type":"B","date":"2018-06","value":"222"},{"type":"C","date":"2018-06","value":"555"},{"type":"D","date":"2018-06","value":"666"},{"type":"A","date":"2018-07","value":"156"},{"type":"B","date":"2018-07","value":"111"},{"type":"C","date":"2018-07","value":"333"},{"type":"D","date":"2018-07","value":"999"}],"number":"111-111"};

// const dates = [...new Set(list.data.map(item => item.date))];
const dates = Array.from(list.data.map(item => item.date));
console.log(dates);

// const types = [...new Set(list.data.map(item => item.type))];
const types = Array.from(list.data.map(item => item.type));
console.log(types)
 
const res = dates.map(date => {
  const obj = {};
  types.map(type => {
    obj[type] = list.data.filter(item => item.date === date && item.type === type)[0].value;
  });
  obj.date = date;
  return obj;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I changed const obj = {}; to const obj = <any>{}; because I had Property does not exist on type '{}' error. And after that I've got error in console "15724 ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).slice is not a function"

Comment: @Jakubbb Or better still, define the interface or typings for obj so that we don't have to resort to using `any` :). Hold on, that error is because of the spread syntax with Set. Let me make the changes

Comment: npm install typescript-collections --save helped me with error https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections

Comment: @Jakubbb A quick fix would be to use `Array.from()` instead of the spread syntax. I have updated my code. Let me see if it works now?

Comment: Yes correct!! Regarding that, you can read up more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439869/can-typescript-compile-to-es6-code and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332394/angular-and-typescript-cant-find-names

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

**TS**

```
let finalArray = [];
let valueA: string = null;
let valueB: string = null;
let valueC: string = null;
// Here data is a variable which contain your JSON data
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data.type === 'A') { 
      valueA = data[i].value;
    }
    if (data.type === 'B') { 
      valueB = data[i].value;
    } 
    if (data.type === 'C') { 
      valueC = data[i].value;
    }
    if (data.type === 'D') {
        finalArray.push({
        month: data[i].date
        A: valueA,
        B: valueB,
        C: valueC,
        D: data[i].value
        });
    }
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

Let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: I think that there should be [i] next to data (data[i].type). It's very good answer but I didn't mention that the number of types can change (so there could be only A,B and C for example) sory for that :(.

Comment: Yes, My bad there should me `i` after the data i modified my answer. If no of type is dynamic them @wentjun answer is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your input is

```
let input = {
        "data": [
            {
                "type": "A",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "153"
            },
            {
                "type": "B",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "888"
            },
            {
                "type": "C",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "999"
            },
            {
                "type": "D",
                "date": "2018-05",
                "value": "555"
            },
            {
                "type": "A",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "148"
            },
            {
                "type": "B",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "222"
            },
            {
                "type": "C",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "555"
            },
            {
                "type": "D",
                "date": "2018-06",
                "value": "666"
            },
            {
                "type": "A",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "156"
            },
            {
                "type": "B",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "111"
            },
            {
                "type": "C",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "333"
            },
            {
                "type": "D",
                "date": "2018-07",
                "value": "999"
            }
        ],
        "number": "111-111"
    };
```

You can do this to get the required result in the `output` variable

```
let output = [];

    input.data.forEach(function (item) {
        const type = item.type;
        const date = item.date;
        const value = item.value;

        let newlyCreated = false;
        let objForMonth = output.find(x => x.month == date);

        if (!objForMonth) {
            newlyCreated = true;
            objForMonth = {};
            objForMonth.month = date;
        }
        objForMonth[type] = value;

        if (newlyCreated) {
            output.push(objForMonth);
        } else {
            let indexToWriteTo = output.findIndex(x => x.month == date);
            output[indexToWriteTo] = objForMonth;
        }
    });
```