# compile typescript code to es6 instead of es5

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, config, ecmascript-5

Currently learning typescript and I noticed that the output code is always using var.
Is it possible to output const and let in the .js file or typescript needs to always output es5 for some reason?
Thanks.

EXAMPLE:

```
// main.ts
const x: number = 2;
let y: string = 'hello';

// main.js
var x = 2;
var y = 'hello';
```

Is this output possible, if so, how?

```
// main.js
const x = 2;
let y = 'hello';
```

Comment: What's your tsconfig? Also, no, because all types are removed at compile time.

Comment: That second example isn't JavaScript and it's identical to the original code.

Comment: type annotations (`: number`, `: string`) are features of TypeScript, not ES6

Comment: yeah, sorry, was a copy/paste error by my part, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add compiler flags to specify a target, e.g. `--target es6`. See this question: [How do I transpile TypeScript to ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439869/how-do-i-transpile-typescript-to-es6)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after adding `tsconfig.js` and set

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

still not working.

Then I run `npx tsc` instead of `npx tsc xxx.ts`, then I get 'const'